# About table view cell indexpath.row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am getting error when i am assigning value to the cell like

```
profileJson = dicData[@"profile"][0];

cell.userName.text = [[profileJson objectForKey:@"First_Name"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

> Error:
>   [__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe5915d7180

If i write this statement

```
cell.userName.text = [profileJson objectForKey:@"First_Name"];
```

The last value is getting assigned. If the `count` is 3 then output looks like this:

Teja

Teja

Teja

For every cell.

Comment: Post the code from your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: It is having lot of data.i cant post it here.

Comment: Its really good to see my name here!!! :P  Are you sure this [profileJson objectForKey:@"First_Name"] returns an array ?

Comment: there are 3 values in my parser but i can see only last value is getting assigned to all cells of table view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This in your "cellForRowAtIndexPath:"  method

```
NSDictionary *profileJson = dicData[@"profile"][indexPath.row];

NSString *userNameString = [profileJson objectForKey:@"First_Name"];

cell.userName.text = userNameString;
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mismatching your code to interrogate the data structure unpacked from the JSON, you haven't included it, but it would seem like you need:

```
profileJson = dicData[@"profile"][indexPath.row];

cell.userName.text = [profileJson objectForKey:@"First_Name"];
```

so you're indexing into the profiles array based on your table index, rather than always taking the first one, and then extracting the first name variable (where you were previously confused about arrays and strings).

Comment: ProfileJson is dictionary.which is coming from parser.
how to assign that to cell

Comment: you can't assign a dictionary, unless you create a cell subclass which accepts it and deals with it, otherwise you need to unpack the dictionary to get the string like in my answer